# Costs in PHP, Is it worth it to read an XML than to list files in a folder?

Tags: php

I'll try to explain myself . I want to show a list of files from a folder in a web using PHP and what I want know is what is better in time and server costs (server requests and data transmissions ) ,

Read an XML with the list of files in it or open the folder and see the files one bye one?

P.D: The list must contain from 100 to 200 files in it.

Comment: You should really test this and then report your results somewhere. I'm really curious about the answer, and suspect that the people answering your question are basically speculating. Of course, both methods are probably too fast to actually matter in the real world.

Comment: I can't promise that , but i'll see it if i have enough time to do both versions with many files , and i'll tell you if i do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 100-200 files, both should be comparable operations, so I'd use whichever of the two you feel more comfortable using and implementing.

**edit:** As far as server requests/data transmissions, why would they be any different, if they're the same list of files?

I'm fairly certain the bottleneck will be I/O rather than PHP: either reading a file, or enumerating a directory. If you increase the # of files to thousands, you'll want to measure the results yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronise the list on each folder update and that should be it. Or you can read folder by using scandir() or glob(). If there aren't many requests you should be fine.